# Amazon S3 client fails when invoked within SOAP over HTTP web service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a class which loads an image to amazon S3 and returns public url to that image. When I run that class as Java application - everything works fine. When I create a SOAP web service from top-down approach and try to invoke that code within web service code - it fails. I know exactly where it fails, but I don't know why and also I can't debug it, doesn't print anything to console, although I'm trying catch errors.

I am getting **java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**. I searched here and amazon forums, couldn't find any suggestions how to solve this problem (I saw many questions with this error, but no solution).

Here's my class to upload image and get url, which works good as Java application:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.HttpMethod;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GeneratePresignedUrlRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

public class S3Uploader {
private String url = null;

public S3Uploader(String filePath){
    setUrl(s3uploadAndGetUrl(filePath));
}


public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String s3uploadAndGetUrl(String file) {
    // get access to S3
    //TODO protect amazon credentials, refer to amazon documentation about proper way of providing credentials.
    String result = null;
    URL url;
    try {
        AWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(
                "myCredentials",
                "myCredentials");
        System.out.println("Credentials loaded.");
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);
        System.out.println("Client created.");

        // image to upload
        File image = new File(file);

        // set expiration date of images' urls
        Calendar origDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar expirationDay = (Calendar) origDay.clone();
        expirationDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
        Date expirationDate = expirationDay.getTime();

        // set bucket and images names
        String bucketName = s3Client.listBuckets().get(0).getName();
        String objectKey = image.getName();

        // upload image
        PutObjectRequest putObject = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName,
                objectKey, image);
        s3Client.putObject(putObject);

        // create and retrieve image url
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(
                bucketName, objectKey);
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expirationDate);

        url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
        result = url.toString();

        System.out.println("Pre-Signed URL = " + url.toString());
        System.out.println();
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = e.getCause().getMessage();
    } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e.getCause().getMessage());
        result = e.getCause().getMessage();
    }

    return result;
}

}
```

Now web service code where I invoke this class:

```
/**
* UrlsCreatorSOAPImpl.java
*
* This file was auto-generated from WSDL
* by the Apache Axis 1.4 Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT) WSDL2Java emitter.
*/

public class UrlsCreatorSOAPImpl implements org.example.www.UrlsCreator.UrlsCreator_PortType{
public java.lang.String getImagesUrls(java.lang.String Url) throws java.rmi.RemoteException {

    S3Uploader upload = new S3Uploader("C:/Users/Maksym/Dropbox/Greece/Matala/IMG_20140508_134143.jpg");
    return upload.getUrl();

 }
}
```

And here is the only thing that gets printed to console:

```
INFO: Credentials loaded.
```

Also SOAP request:

```
- <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:q0="http://www.example.org/UrlsCreator/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <soapenv:Body>
 - <q0:GetImagesUrls>
    <Url>asdasdadsa</Url>
   </q0:GetImagesUrls>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

And SOAP response:

```
- <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <soapenv:Body>
  - <soapenv:Fault>
    <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode> 
    <faultstring>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException</faultstring> 
   - <detail>
     <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">Maksym-PC</ns1:hostname> 
   </detail>
  </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Please help if you can and let me know if I need to provide any additional info. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:** I downloaded java aws sdk 2-3 days ago, so it should be the latest one. Here is a list of jar files under WEB-INF/lib:

```
 aws-java-sdk-1.7.10-javadoc.jar
 aws-java-sdk-1.7.10.jar
 aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.7.10.jar
 axis.jar
 commons-codec-1.3.jar
 commons-discovery-0.2.jar
 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
 commons-logging.jar
 httpclient-4.2.3.jar
 httpcore-4.2.jar
 jackson-annotations-2.1.1.jar
 jackson-core-2.1.1.jar
 jackson-databind-2.1.1.jar
 jaxrpc.jar
 joda-time-2.2.jar
 saaj.jar
 wsdl4j.jar
```

**SOLUTION:** as it turned out - the problem was with glassfish or just my laptop, I don't know. I tried from scratch on another laptop, with the same eclipse version, same glassfish and it worked, I still don't know what was wrong with my laptop (other webservices run smoothly, cleaning projects and server didn't help either).

Anyway, thanks for trying to help =)

Comment: Thank you, I will try it and write back.

Comment: Thanks again, that library didn't help, but problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you're using the same library API version when running the code as you were when developing/compiling your code. And in the case of the remote S3 API, make sure that the version you have on the client side is compatible with the server side version.

Comment: I just downloaded java aws sdk and use it for java application and for web service, same libraries if I understood properly your comment.